# Style in NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

Currently I am using NativeBase in my React Native expo project. However I don't understand style of NativeBase components. 
For example this is the code I have.

```
            <Box style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
              // image here
            </Box>
            <Box marginLeft={20}>
              // image here
            </Box>
            <Box style={{ marginLeft: 50 }}>
              // image here
            </Box>
            <Box marginLeft={50}>
              // image here
            </Box>
```

And this is the result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fygVq.jpg
Can someone explain this to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must differentiate between styling using

- the [`style`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style) prop that is available for every React Native core component and also in NativeBase components because they [implement](https://docs.nativebase.io/box#h2-props) React Native's `View` (used for Box 1 and 3 in your example)
- utility props exposed by NativeBase (used for Box 2 and 4 in your example)

When using the `style` prop, you're stating absolute values. Using the utility props exposed by NativeBase, you're stating [design tokens](https://docs.nativebase.io/next/design-tokens) that translate to a specific absolute value. The design system has the advantage of customization: adapting the design tokens propagates to your whole application.

Answer (score -1):

NativeBase does not have token `50` for spacing. You can refer [this](https://docs.nativebase.io/next/design-tokens#page-title) to read about design tokens in NativeBase.